# Not multicast packets sent over network returns

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, network-programming

Good day all.

My software uses a multicast group to send out messages, however the application acts as a client and server, thus it sends out udp packets and also receives them.

This is tested with text containing 2 000 char's.

I create a queue containing byte[1024] arrays containing the data which needs to be sent.

**Problem:**

The problem lies at receiving these multicast packets, out of 5 packets sent, I mostly receive only 1, regularly 2, etc, and handful of times I received all of them.

Sending and receiving results are as follows:

- packets sent:     1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are sent
- packets returned: 1, 2, 3, 4, F (F is last packet in the sequence, i.e. closing packet)

> 12345
>   134F
>
> 12345
>   1F
>
> 12345
>   134F
>
> 12345
>   14F
>
> 12345
>   1F
>
> 12345
>   1F
>
> 12345
>   1
>
> 12345
>   1
>
> 12345
>   1
>
> 12345
>   1234F
>
> 12345
>   1F
>
> 12345
>   1
>
> 12345
>   1
>
> 12345
>   1
>
> 12345
>   14F
>
> 12345
>   1F
>
> 12345
>   1F
>
> 12345
>   1
>
> 12345
>   1
>
> 12345
>   1
>
> 12345
>   1F
>
> 12345
>   1

**Sending a multicast packet as follows:**

```
        Socket _listener_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        foreach (IPAddress localIP in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).Where(i => i.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
        {
            //handle image and files                
            _listener_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(_MultiIP, localIP));
            _listener_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 1);
            _listener_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            _listener_socket.MulticastLoopback = true;
            _listener_socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(_MultiIP, _PORT));
            while (count > 0)
            {      
                count--;              
                byte[] temp = (byte[])(MSGS_TO_SEND.Dequeue());
                _listener_socket.Send(temp, _BYTE_BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None);
                MSGS_TO_SEND.Enqueue(temp);
            }
        }
        _listener_socket.Close();
```

One thread is for receiving packets and add them to a Queue for processing, and a second thread is for processing. Reason for 2 threads was possibly too much processing in the receiving thread was causing this "packet loss", but unfortunately it did not solve the problem

**Receive Thread:**

```
//initialise multicast group and bind to interface
        Socket _sender_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _PORT);
        _sender_socket.Bind(ipep);
        IPAddress localip = _MultiIP;
        _sender_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(localip, IPAddress.Any));
        Q_RECIEVE = new Queue<char[]>();
        while (_sender_socket.IsBound && !bStop)
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[_BYTE_BUFFER_SIZE];
            _sender_socket.Receive(b);
            char[] chars = new char[_BYTE_BUFFER_SIZE];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(b, 0, chars, 0, b.Length);
            Q_RECIEVE.Enqueue(chars);
        }
```

Comment: UDP is a best-effort protocol, with no method to make sure all segments are received. You should expect to not received all UDP segments sent, and that is known up front when designing. If you require reliability, use TCP, but you can't multicast with TCP since multicast is one-way, and TCP requires two-way.

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks for the response, what do you suggest I could do to get the best performance for my software, decrease packet size, "double" send a packet?

Answer (score 1):

There are reliable UDP protocols and libraries for them. I've used UDT (http://udt.sourceforge.net/) before and it worked fine. I'm not aware of a C# wrapper for it, but there might be one or another reliable UDP C# implementation.

Other than that, here are some other suggestions:

1. Multicasting is mostly problematic on the switch(es). Try to change them, if you can. Sometimes it can be a problem on the routers, too, so, you may try to change them, too, if possible.
2. Try sending less packets (or less often). Packet length should not be that much of a problem if you're below 1500 bytee, but, you can also try to decrease the length.
3. To be sure that you're not missing packets in your code for some reason, use a packet sniffer and see if the packets actually arrived at your destination computer. WireShark has a nice enough GUI, but there are several GUI and CLI based ones out there.

Comment: thanks for the answer. 1. I am testing this on a router, home router actually. 2. I am sticking to a multicast tutorial suggestion of 1024 bytes, which also seems overly-sufficient. 3. Wireshark report the same information in detailed form as I posted. It report packet 1, 4, 5 has been sent, other times it reports packets 1 has been sent. However my code for sending the packets is not problematic since at times I receive all my packets I have sent. Why would this "loss" occur?

Comment: Well, like any other packet, it can be lost for many reasons, from some physical (more or less transient) problem to SW issues. Multicast adds the problem of having to "clone" the packet at the router and the switch(es), adding to congestion and possible buffer issues (overflow or other). That's why playing with timing and message duration might help, to some degree. Having said all that, your failure rate seems pretty high, that's why I think there may be a HW issue (also).